# don't want to use col-sm-# for (>=1200px)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My `.container` has fixed width of 960px. I have used `col-lg-#` but when I resize page to a smaller width than 1200px, that div spans the whole width. Is there any way that I don't need to include col-sm-# and col-md-# ?

```
.container{
    width:960px;
    border:2px solid red;
    height:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
} 
<div class="container">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Helo i have asked a dam question...

Comment: Is anyone there??????

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how bootstrap's responsiveness works. you've also misunderstood the format here... please define "does not work" by telling what you want, and what it's doing.

Comment: @ShawnTaylor I know the working of col-xm-#, col-sm-# , col-md-# and  col-lg-#
I think my question is making sense.
Why -1 ??

Comment: The input field in container class has width of 3 grids (col-lg-3).
But when i resize page to width less than 1200px the input filed takes the whole browser window width. Is there any way to have fixed width of input field without using col-sm-# and col-md-#

Comment: I didn't -1, but it's probably because your question is not clear. "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us what you expect to happen.

Comment: Why are you using col-lg-# ?

Comment: Because i don't want input filed to take whole page width.

Comment: Ok, well unless you include another col class, it will revert to the default (col-12) once below the lg threshold. Use col-xs-3 if you want it to span 3/12ths of the width on every device. Bootstrap 3 is "mobile first" so you start with how you want it to behave on xs.

Comment: ps - there is no col-ms. there is col-xs, col-sm, col-md, col-lg.

Comment: sorry ms was typed by mistake. Its 'sm'.

Comment: @ShawnTaylor This is not a good answer. In my website i have used col-lg-1 , col-lg-2, col-lg-3, col-lg-4 and col-lg-6. So i have to write to much classes.

Comment: It may not be an answer you like, but it's right:)

Comment: @ShawnTaylor Please answer the question that i posted below your answer.

Comment: Better to post a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding how the col classes work. In short, YES you do have to declare the col classes you want below lg, if they are not the default of col-*-12. In this case, you should do

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
```

as opposed to `col-lg-3`.

Bootstrap grid classes apply to all declared device widths **and above**... so `col-xs-3` applies to `xs`, `sm`, `md`, and `lg`. `Col-md-3` applies to `md` and `lg`, but `xs` and `sm` default to 12. And in your example, `col-lg-3`, ONLY applies to `lg`, and as soon as the window shrinks below the lg threshold (1200px) it defaults to col-12.

This can be a difficult concept to explain, but it makes so much sense once you get it.

Comment: <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top col-xs-12">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
Not working for navbar. When i shrink window nav bar becomes vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Use  col-xs-# instead of col-lg-#

```
<div class="container">
       <form role="form">
           <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-xs-4">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" />
               </div>
           </div>
       </form>
    </div>
```

It worked!!